# I am using the IDE Eclipse and since the next restart the mouse cursor is flickering the whole time

Tags: eclipse

You can read my problem in the headline. I didnt change anything. It happened after the next restart.

Comment: What version of Eclipse? What OS?

Comment: I am running windows 10 and have the latest version of eclipse.